# HTML / CSS, getting 2 backgrounds in each side to adjust with the wrapper

Tags: html, css

im trying to have 2 seperate backgrounds on my website, one in each side, that adjust acording to screen size

like on [ownedcore.com](http://www.ownedcore.com/) where the sides adjust with the mid wrapper

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bleft"></div>
<div id="wrapper">a</div>
<div id="bright"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@charset "utf-8";

header, section, footer, aside, bside, article, figure {display: block;}
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#wrapper {
    width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
}

#bleft {
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(images/pageBGLeft.jpg);
    clear: left;
}
#bright {
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    float: right;
    background-image: url(images/pageBGRight.jpg);
    clear: right;
}
```

Does not force the right background right, but displays the one line wrapper

Answer (score 2):

That site looks like it works with 2 backgrounds on 2 containers like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="A">
    <div id="B">
      <div id="wrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

then css:

```
#A {
  background: url(...) top right no-repeat;
}
#B {
  background: url(...) top left no-repeat;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Interesting technique, I've never seen it before. Is it common?

Comment: Maybe not common - more common with fixed layouts is to have one image centered. But I've seen it. Works best if you have full-height content column.

Comment: At the risk of doing it all for you, edited answer to show content #wrapper.

Comment: Yeaaah, no ... the wrapper stacks on A/B which are stacked on eachother :)

Comment: @user1831170 - If you look at the source of the site you linked, willoller's code is exactly what they do. The images are only about 700px wide, and since the right image is positioned on the right side of its element, which expands with the window, it appears to adjust. The margin on the wrapper keeps the content area centered, so the images appear to "move" when the browser is resized.

Comment: Here it is in action (hotlinking the backgrounds in question even) http://jsfiddle.net/hWbNM/2/

Comment: thank you, very much, how do i force the wrapper mid, and the backgrounds to go around it ? Its just sampled as 1 picture background atm

Comment: I don't think I can make it simpler than in the jsfiddle. Use `margin: 0 auto` to center the container, and the rest is there. Make sure you are looking at http://jsfiddle.net/hWbNM/2

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use `<img>` elements instead.  Maybe you can try `position:fixed` and have one be `left: 0` and the other `left: 50%`. with the width of each to `50%` and height auto... may have to play around a bit, but I think that concept should work