# Get full page div columns to fit inside page when content is little

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with an html layout.
The basic ides is that between the header and footer there are 3 columns.
The middle column is fixed and the sides are whatever is left.
Both sides must have different image backgrounds. 
You can see what I mean here -> http://assets.nbn-studio.com/3cols.html.
The problem is that content is sometimes smaller than the window but since I've set the columns at 100% the footer is always below the page bottom.
I've tried different things but can't seem to get it right.
Don't mind the images but I had to show some meaning. Also all of this must work in IE7 and above.
Also the sides will have no content but the background images.
I'd be thankful for any ideas.

UPDATE:
Here's what I'm talking about:

[image: Demonstration of the problem]

Link to image: http://i49.tinypic.com/1zeju2t.jpg

Comment: How do you want the page to behave when you have enough content to force the page to scroll vertically?

Comment: It should behave as normally expected. If there's enough content the elements between the header and footer stretch to display all the contents. If the content is so small that there's no vertical scroll needed - then the page must fill all the space.

Comment: The reason that I asked is that some people like to fix or pin the footer to the bottom of the page and allow the main content to scroll beneath it.

Comment: I am looking over your HTML, what you need is fairly advanced.  Please check back tomorrow, I will try to post an answer for you.  Have a good evening!

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I'll check back. Good evening to you too!

Comment: I posted an updated with a version that does not use `table-cell`, so this might work for IE7.

Comment: Thanks for that! This is going to be just fine. Appreciate all the effort! Good evening!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one solution which has some minor limitations but will work reasonably well for browsers newer than IE6/7.

You can see the working page at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/6jnWE/show/

and view the code and CSS at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/6jnWE

The CSS looks like:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    background: url(http://assets.nbn-studio.com/apache_pb.gif) #CC0;
    height: 10%;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
#wrap-outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    display: table;
}
#side-left {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: url(http://assets.nbn-studio.com/arrow-left-2.png) right top repeat;
    height: inherit;
}
#left-content {
    float: right;
    background: url(http://assets.nbn-studio.com/arrow-left.png) repeat-y;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 800px;
    background: url(http://assets.nbn-studio.com/knot.png) repeat;
}
#side-right {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: url(http://assets.nbn-studio.com/arrow-right-2.png) left top repeat;
    height: inherit;
}
#right-content {
    float: left;
    background: url(http://assets.nbn-studio.com/arrow-right.png) repeat-y;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
}
#footer {
    background: #6C9;
    height: 10%;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
```

In this approach, I declared `display: table` for `#wrap-outer` and `display: table-cell` for `#side-left`, `#content`, and `#side-right`.  I could probably have used some absolutely positioned elements to achieve a similar effect.

The key though is to set relative heights for `#header`, `#wrap-outer` and `#footer` to 10%, 80% and 10% respectively.  The reality is that you can't mix height units of % and px without some seeing the vertical scroll bar for small enough window sizes.  My compromise is to set a `min-height` value for the header and footer and design any artwork to have some flexibility.  If the vertical scroll appears on a small screen, one can live with that.

Also, note the use of `height: inherit` for `#side-left` and `#side-right`.

**Use Multiple Background Images**

If you are focusing on newer browsers that support CSS3, you can simplify the markup by using multiple images in `#wrap-outer` and eliminate the background images all together in `#side-left` and `#left-content` elements (similarly for the right hand side).

**Use of table-cell**

The `table-cell` property is not supported in IE6/7 and that may be an issue for some users.

**Fix for IE7**

I came up with an alternative layout that does not use `table-cell`.

You can view it at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/c7vTL/

I positioned the side panels using `position: absolute`.

I made a few modifications to allow this version to work:

1. The central background image is pinned to the wrapper instead of the content element.  This required setting a background color to the side bars (white).
2. Overflow on the wrapper is hidden.

Comment: Again thanks for the effort. My first attempt was similar but since `table-cell` is not supported by IE7 it was rejected. IE6 support is not a demand, but IE7 is. Other than that this solution indeed works very well for newer browsers.

Comment: The use of table cell was more to get the backgrounds to work in the sidebars.  I could get it to work with some positioning techniques.  How do you feel about setting relative heights for the header and footer?

Comment: I really don't know. The header will contain a logo and some controls so maybe it's not a problem. The footer is actually just a bottom bar with a `repeat-x` image of set height. It should look kind of "like a frame that marks the bottom of the page".

Comment: The alternative is to use jQuery/JavaScript to calculate the height of `#wrap-outer`.

Comment: I'm trying to use `jQuery(document).ready` and `jQuery(document).resize` but am probably doing it wrong. I've updated the page at the link. Could you please take a look and give me some advice on where I'm failing.

Comment: Ok. I forgot to remove the `min-height: 100%;' on the `#wrap-outer` so it wasn't doing anything. It seems to work now. I'm inclined to use this alternative until/if I come across some other way of doing it without js.

Comment: Actually I think I'll put the styles you suggested as a css for `<!--[if gte IE 8]>` and the current styles for `<!--[if lte IE 7]>`. I thinks it's going to be better not to go over all of this if the client browser is a newer/different than IE7. 
Thanks for the support and the effort.

Comment: Brilliant! I think a separate IE7 style sheet is the way to do.  It sounds like you are in pretty good shape at this point.

Answer (score -1):

Im not entirely sure what the question is however this might be able to help you:

[HTML / CSS, getting 2 backgrounds in each side to adjust with the wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748450/html-css-getting-2-backgrounds-in-each-side-to-adjust-with-the-wrapper)

Comment: It seems that the particular question is more about multiple backgrounds and width.  
My issue is height.